# how to solve exceptions which is showing a null exception error while installing netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans-8

**NetBeans error message:**

[image: NetBeans error message]

how to solve this please help me 
its not getting installed help me I am unable to do so I need it but cant do anything.

Comment: check on the website of NetBeans what version of Java is required for that version of NetBeans

Comment: Welcome @kanishk, I recommend you view the [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page

Comment: [1] Ensure that you have JDK 8 installed before installing NetBeans. [2] The screen shot gives you the name of the log file. Update your post with any relevant messages in that log.